# RSS/VSS are growing unstopped until all memory & swap on machine ends

Tags: java, linux, memory, rhel

We have a weblogic 9.2 server with Java1.5.0.16 on RHEL5.3 that we deploy on it a web service and an Alfresco content management system.

We were running it fine for ~3 years on HP-UX i11.23 and a month ago we moved to Linux RH5.3 and from time to time (it happened 3 times) we noticed that the process is starting to use more and more memory until all the memory and swap on the machine ends.

The process still works fine and all the log files looks normal (as if nothing happened) including GC log.

```
Glance for process ID 25450:

B0000A Glance C.04.70.000 06:54:05 supra2 x86_64 Current Avg High
CPU Util SU | 2% 2% 2%
Disk Util D D | 97% 97% 97%
Mem Util U U | 98% 98% 98%
Swap Util U U | 60% 60% 60%
Resources PID: 25450, java PPID: 25394 euid: 664 User:afspr04
CPU Usage (util): 5.40 Total RSS : 40.6gb
User CPU : 3.60 Text VSS : 56kb
System CPU : 1.80 Data VSS : 66.1gb
Priority : 15 Stack VSS : 2.0mb
Nice Value : 0 Total VSS : 66.5gb
Blocked On : SLEEP
Major Faults : 235
Minor Faults : 164
Processor : 1
Argv1: weblogic.Server
Cmd : /opt/java1.5.0_16/bin/java -Dweblogic.Name=dmcmsserver -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/etc -server -javaagent:/opt/MercuryDiagn
ostics/JavaAgent/DiagnosticsAgent/lib/probeagent.jar -Dprobe.id=supra2_afspr04_dmcms_ear_p4 -Dprobe.group=CMS_SERVER -D
points.file.name=/opt/MercuryDiagnostics/JavaAgent/DiagnosticsAgent/etc/supra2_afspr04_dmcms_ear_p4 -Dcom.wily.introsco
pe.agent.agentName=DMCMS -Xms7g -Xmx7g -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=1792m -XX:MaxNewSize=1792m -X
X:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xnoclassg
c -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/etc -Dweblogic.Stderr=/app/afspr04/dmcms_ear_p4/dmcmsdomain/logs/online.l
og -Dweblogic.Stdout=/app/afspr04/dmcms_ear_p4/dmcmsdomain/logs/online.log -Damdocs.system.home=/app/afspr04/dmcms_ear_
p4/properties/jesi -Damdocs.messageHandling.home=/app/afspr04/dmcms_ear_p4/properties/jesi -Djesi.config.loader=amdocs.
ecommerce.esi.utils.config.InterfaceConfigXPathLoader -Damdocs.uams.config.resource=config/mvc/ldap ...
```

pmap shows the big allocation as anonymous
pmap (sorted by the big once):

```
25450: /opt/java1.5.0_16/bin/java -Dweblogic.Name=dmcmsserver -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/etc -server -javaagent:/opt/MercuryDiagnostics/JavaAgent/DiagnosticsAgent/lib/probeagent.jar -Dprobe.id=supra2_afspr04_dmcms_ear_p4 -Dprobe.group=CMS_SERVER -Dpoints.file.name=/opt/MercuryDiagnostics/JavaAgent/DiagnosticsAgent/etc/supra2_afspr04_dmcms_ear_p4 -Dcom.wily.introscope.agent.agentName=DMCMS -Xms7g -Xmx7g -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=1792m -XX:MaxNewSize=1792m -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivo
00002ab0f8000000    10518548    rwx--   [anon]
00002ab798009000    8388612 rwx--   [anon]
000000005fcce000    8038976 rwx--   [anon]
00002aac7aab0000    7602176 rwx--   [anon]
00002aaf74000000    5259284 rwx--   [anon]
00002ab688000000    4194308 rwx--   [anon]
00002aae4b930000    1684124 rwx--   [anon]
00002aab80000000    1314836 rwx--   [anon]
00002aab20000000    655376  rwx--   [anon]
00002aac28000000    532488  rwx--   [anon]
00002aac50000000    524292  rwx--   [anon]
00002aaaec000000    327696  rwx--   [anon]
00002aaad8000000    131088  rwx--   [anon]
00002ab658000000    131060  rwx--   [anon]
00002ab0dc000000    131044  rwx--   [anon]
00002aaacc2f5000    114708  rwx--   [anon]
...
total 69733292K
```

Have anyone encountered something similar?

Thanks,
Oz

Answer (score 0):

What is the CPU/RAM of the server you are using? You should consult the [RHEL compatibility matrix for WLS 9.2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs/rhelinux/rhel50_92.html) and make sure your JDK/CPU configuration is a supported combination. Also, since you might want to consider JRockit as your JVM if that's an option for you. Finally, also try lowering the max heap space (-Xmx and -Xms) and see if the server is more stable.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply. 
CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R)E5540  @ 2.53GHz, RAM 48g, JDK 1.5.0.16 and configuration is supported.

Since we just switched to Linux (from HP-UX i), we will probably examine JRockit in the future for performance reasons.

Thanks,
Oz

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit kernel? And have you tried upgrading to JDK 1.5.0_22?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same kind of problems here with a different OS (Sun Solaris 10 - 32bit) but I see a common point : the Introscope.

We suspected it to allocate memory too much (memory leak ?) as it uses a native library (*.so accessed through JNI).

To understand my point, there is something which I need to make clear in this case about the JVM process's memory : the whole memory of the Java process is split in two different parts, the native and the Java ones.

The memory for the Java part (the one managed by the Garbage Collector) can be monitored through standard JVM API. Just remember that, in Java, you can only monitor this part of the JVM process's memory. It contains the heap (eden & 2 survivors), oldgen, permgen. This part of the memory is usually the biggest one, this is why there are ways to monitor it, while there is none for the rest.

The rest of the process's memory, the native part, is different. It is made up of the network sockets/buffers, file descriptors/buffers, GC actual data structures and buffers, the native libraries buffers, the native code compiled by the JIT compiler, and some other inner JVM specific things. There is also the executable code of the JVM and the native libraries. There is usually no standard way (often no way at all) to look in this part, except using a debugger.

After asking to C&A about Wily / Introscope's native lib, they explained us that :

- it allocates memory dynamically ;
- there is no way to limit its memory consumption ;
- there is no way to predict its memory consumption ;
- it is used by Wily only to collect underlying system's specific measures (e.g. OS flags, CPU Load, Total free memory, number of processes, ...), as Introscope is using the Java Agent API for everything else.

For 99% of the applications, the "native" part of the memory (the non-Java part) is negligible compared with the Java part.

But here, with the Introscope playing in our game, things become different as the native part may grow arbitrarily big and eat process's memory space up to the limits.

We concluded here that those system specific values are not very interesting for us -- and I think this is the case for many of you as there are other ways to get them : mem, free, top, taskmanager, ... -- so we decided to remove it. Simply.

I believe this is the best option.

Try it and tell us if it solved your memory problems.